# Using ccache when building inside of docker

Tags: docker, ccache

I am working on moving the build for a C++ project into a docker image.  The image will be built and pushed by a Jenkins job.  Prior to docker, I made heavy use of ccache to speed up my builds on Jenkins, especially in the case of builds where very little changed.  The trouble with docker is that the build now runs in an isolated environment, so I can no longer benefit from ccache.  Is there a way to build inside of an ephemeral container while still taking advantage of ccache?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK as promised.

### Prereqs

1. Be on Docker 18.06 or above
2. Run in experimental mode, on client and server (at time of writing)

### Setup experimental Mode

Server:
I created the following systemd override file:

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --experimental -H fd://
```

I then did a `systemctl daemon-reload ; systemctl restart docker.service`

Client side you need to set and env variable
`export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`

### Docker file

This is the basis of the docker file. I am building a php image, but you can build whatever you want. The key parts of the 1st line comment (needed to tell docker to parse the file in experimental mode), and the `--mount=type=cache,target=/ccache/` option. This pulls in the cache folder for that stage of the build. Make sure you put it on every RUN line where you trigger a compile

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM php:7.3-fpm-stretch

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# setup locales
RUN apt update && \
  apt install -y locales && \
  sed -i -e 's/# en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
  locale-gen

ENV LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
ENV LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
ENV CCACHE_DIR=/ccache

RUN apt update ; apt install -yq \
        git \
        cloud-guest-utils \
        iproute2 \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxslt1-dev \
        libmemcached-dev \
        libgd-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libmemcached-dev \
        ccache \
        awscli


# use ccache (make it appear in path earlier then /usr/bin/gcc etc)
RUN for p in gcc g++ cc c++; do ln -vs /usr/bin/ccache /usr/local/bin/$p;  done

# prod format
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/ccache/ docker-php-source extract && \
    docker-php-ext-install \
    intl \
    bcmath  \
    calendar \
    exif \
    gd \
    gettext \
    mysqli \
    opcache \
    pcntl \
    pdo_mysql \
    shmop \
    soap \
    sockets \
    sysvmsg \
    sysvsem \
    sysvshm \
    xsl \
    zip \
  && \
  docker-php-source delete
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/ccache/ ccache -s
```

### Sample output

I am running the build with the `--progress plain` flag as the output in experimental is very different

```
#25 [16/16] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/ccache/ ccache -s 
#25 digest: sha256:98c661a0404c71176a4bbf7d02123184524a784fabb2575d5210da088f16ee3a 
#25 name: "[16/16] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/ccache/ ccache -s" 
#25 started: 2019-07-01 09:35:15.158199623 +0000 UTC 
#25 0.468 cache directory /ccache 
#25 0.468 primary config /ccache/ccache.conf 
#25 0.468 secondary config (readonly) /etc/ccache.conf 
#25 0.468 cache hit (direct) 2450 
#25 0.468 cache hit (preprocessed) 152 
#25 0.468 cache miss 590 
#25 0.468 cache hit rate 81.52 % 
#25 0.468 called for link 163 
#25 0.468 called for preprocessing 1011 
#25 0.468 compile failed 33 
#25 0.468 preprocessor error 3 
#25 0.468 bad compiler arguments 188 
#25 0.468 autoconf compile/link 943 #25 0.468 no input file 554 
#25 0.468 cleanups performed 0 
#25 0.468 files in cache 1288 #25 0.468 cache size 20.6 MB
#25 0.468 max cache size 5.0 GB 
#25 completed: 2019-07-01 09:35:15.732702254 +0000 UTC 
#25 duration: 574.502631ms
```

More readings here:
https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#description

Answer (score 18):

You can still use ccache in conjunction with your build.

Create a [Data Volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/data-volumes) to allow data to persist between compilations/builds using the following command:

```
$ docker create -v /mnt/ccache:/ccache --name ccache debian
```

Then create your container that “mounts” the data container created above using the `--volumes-from` command line option.

```
$ docker run -e CCACHE_DIR=/ccache --volumes-from ccache -it debian
```

Now you'll be in the shell of the debian container and can install the required apps and test ccache:

```
root@15306d02505a:/# apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc ccache
```

Now at this point you can check the cache, and it will be empty as expected:

```
root@15306d02505a:/# ccache -s
cache directory                     /ccache
cache hit (direct)                     0
cache hit (preprocessed)               0
cache miss                             0
files in cache                         0
cache size                             0 Kbytes
max cache size                       1.0 Gbytes
```

The data volume will persist, so even after the container is terminated, the cache is still there. Future builds that mount the volume (and specify the -e ENV variable) will utilize the cache.

Then create a simple app, run it, and check the cache again:

```
root@15306d02505a:/# cat > foo.c << __EOF__
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
     return 0;
 }
 __EOF__

root@15306d02505a:/# PATH=/usr/lib/ccache:$PATH gcc -o foo.o -c foo.c
root@15306d02505a:/# ccache -s
cache directory                     /ccache
cache hit (direct)                     1
cache hit (preprocessed)               0
cache miss                             1
files in cache                         2
cache size                             8 Kbytes
max cache size                       1.0 Gbytes
```

You can see the cache is now populated, and further builds will see performance improvements because of it.

The data volume will persist, so even after the container is terminated, the cache is still there. Future builds that mount the volume (and specify the -e `ENV` variable) will utilize the cache.

This blog post does a good job of explaining it:

[Using Ccache with Docker](https://web.archive.org/web/20200131005945/http://frungy.org/docker/using-ccache-with-docker/)

Comment: The trouble is (and I might just be misunderstanding) that I am wanting to create an image as a result of my build.  This approach seems to let me use ccache in a container but not with a docker build command.

Comment: You could add `ccache` into your Dockerfile using the `RUN` command, or use Docker Compose to mount & use the volume during `docker-compose build`. You can also save a container to an image using `docker commit`.

Comment: Yeah, I think combining the above with "docker commit" is probably the best route.  Thank you.

Comment: Will this setup have any issues with multiple containers and builds accessing the same cache?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, its a good one for runtime but not build time. If i find a correct answer I will post back

Comment: This allows for a non-hermetic build and CI/CD cannot take advantage of caching with a solution like this.

Comment: Blog post is gone

Comment: @AlexReinking - Updated to a cached version in WayBackMachine